# Loading Custom Data into TensorFlow with .get_file()

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow2.0

I'm relatively new to Tensor Flow and Stack overflow, so please be patient. My question is as follows: 'How do I load in a custom dataset spreadsheet into TensorFlow using the .get_file() method and pandas read method?' I  have searched the TensorFlow website, stack overflow, and other websites but they all seem to either use publically available data online or do some strange imports with different methods that I do not understand. Here is what I currently have:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd


CSV_COLUMN_NAMES = ['SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth', 'Species']
SPECIES = ['Setosa', 'Versicolor', 'Virginica']
# This is just some flower data online

train_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    "iris_training.csv", "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv")
test_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    "iris_test.csv", "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv")
    # I have a spreadsheet on my machine with the exact same data. I want to use those files instead

train = pd.read_csv(train_path, names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)
test = pd.read_csv(test_path, names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)
# Here I am reading a csv file inputting the data, labels, and defining header. Should I use pd.read_excel instead because the files on my machine are excel files?

train_y = train.pop('Species')
test_y = test.pop('Species') # removes answers/thing to predict and test against
```

Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: Or if there was a way to manipulate the data online through the google dataset, that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to load in a custom CSV? In order to do that you can use pandas as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', delimiter = ',', encoding='latin-1', header=0)
```

If you are using a IDE such as Jupyter Notebook you need to download the csv onto Jupyter notebook before running this command. You can do this with:
[image: How to upload files to Jupyter Notebook]

Comment: could you please explain a bit more about the delimiter and encoding please? Also, I am not using an ide like that, I am using pycharm, so does that mean I need to move the excel file into the project's folder? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @MasonChoi Delimiter and encoding are parameters of the function pd.read_csv(). They are extra commands you can add when importing your csv. In this case, delimiter and encoding are just ways to format your data into a form which looks like an excel sheet. For example, in setting the delimiter as "," you say that wherever there is a comma in the dataset you make another datapoint. This is a link to all of the functions you can use when importing a file using pd.read_csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html .

Comment: As for pycharm, I am not too familiar with it but I found this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/import-data.html. If you scroll down it shows how to import csv files. If that doesn't work then you can try to see if just running the command above works without importing anything to PyCharm directly.